# What are nuts and super-nuts in Saki's "Beasts and Super-Beasts"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, saki

In Saki's [*Beasts and Super-Beasts*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/269/269-h/269-h.htm) he refers to "Nuts" and "Super-Nuts".  For example, we have

> “You are not going to be what they call a Nut, are you?” she inquired with some anxiety, partly with the idea that a Nut would be an extravagance which her sister’s small household would scarcely be justified in incurring, partly, perhaps, with the instinctive apprehension that a Nut, even in its embryo stage, would refuse to carry parcels.

in *The Dreamer* and

> He was a youngish man of ordinary appearance, quiet of dress and unobtrusive of manner, and he could never wholly rid himself of the idea that a fierce light of public scrutiny beat on him as though he had been a notability or a super-nut.

in *A Holiday Task*.

I suspect this usage would have briefly fashionable, prior to the First World War, when the stories were first published in the *Morning Post*.

So what is meant by "nut"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **nut, *n.* 6.c.** *British slang.* A fashionable or showy young man. Cf. knut *n.*, nutty *adj.* 4. *Obsolete.*
>
> 1904   in *Notes & Queries* (1913) 26 July 78/1   I'm one of the nuts, one of the nibs.
> 1913   *Punch* 12 Feb. 115/1   Spring socks will be black and Spring ties a quiet blue. A strike of nuts is expected at any moment.
> 1920   W. J. Locke *House of Baltazar* xvii. 205   I've a jolly good mind to set him up regardless, like a pre-war nut—with solid silver boot-trees and the rest to correspond.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

A search of the British Newspaper Archive finds that “super-nut” had a brief vogue in 1913–1914, and then vanished rapidly with the coming of the war. This cartoon by [Lewis Baumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Baumer) from *Punch* for 8th April 1914 gives some idea of what people thought a “super-nut” might look like:

[image: A nervous young man is being fitted with a striped suit by a shop assistant while a smart young man points at him with a stick. The smart young man wears a top-hat, a tight-waited black jacket, striped trousers, patent leather shoes, and has a monocle on a chain. Caption reads, “A special feature of the gent’s ready-to-wear clothing department will be the attendance, daily of a super-“nut” (from the Gaiety or Daly’s), who will give free advice to each purchaser of Easter outfits.”]

(The [Gaiety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaiety_Theatre,_London) and [Daly’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daly%27s_Theatre) were two theatres in the West End of London.)